# Количество тактов за операцию с++

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Есть ли таблица с описанием сколько примерно тактов процессора использует функция или операция с++ на русском?
Измерять все вручную неохота и долго.

Update: Измерял количество тактов вставкой ассемблера на linux.

Пример на англ
[image: Таблиця тактов]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109290/discussion-on-question-by------).